# Ionic localstorage doesn't persist

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

I'm using local storage for storing data in Ionic 
My problem is that the local storage doesn't persist as it does on Web.

On iOS the local storage is being deleted every few days and on Android it's worse and on some devices the local storage acts like a session storage and being wiped when the app closed.

This is my local storage service:

```
angular.module('app.core')
.factory('localstorage', ['$window', function ($window) {
  return {
    setObject: function (key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function (key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || null);
    }
  }
}]);
```

I read this post: http://www.joshmorony.com/a-summary-of-local-storage-options-for-phonegap-applications/

> Local storage gets a bit of a bad wrap, and is generally considered to
>   be unreliable. I think the browsers local storage can be a viable
>   option and it is reasonably stable and reliable, but, it is possible
>   for the data to be wiped, which means for a lot of applications it’s
>   not going to be a great option.

Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: well maybe thats why Ionic 2 uses SqlStorage: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/SqlStorage/

Comment: @Akis_Tfs unfortunately I have an app writing in ionic and angular 1.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After exploring the localstorage issue usage in ionic I can say one thing:

**DO NOT USE IT** if you need your data to be persisted!

I've decided to use **PouchDB** to keep my data persistent.

From [Ashteya Biharisingh post](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/):

> The data that is saved in localStorage is supposed to be persisted
>   even if you close the app or turn off your phone. In most cases this
>   will work, but there are issues with the way iOS and Android manage
>   localStorage on the devices.
>
> **iOS**
>   On iOS 8 the localStorage is sometimes cleared when memory is low, as you can read here.
>
> I recently experienced it myself on an Ionic app I was working on. I
>   got a notification on my iPhone that it was running low on memory and
>   when I opened up the app the localStorage was empty. I had another app
>   on my device that was using localStorage as well, but that one was not
>   cleared.
>
> **Android**
>   I haven't tested this extensively on Android, but if you read this thread, you'll see that there are several reports that localStorage doesn't work as expected.

you can follow a pretty good guide [here](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/)